# How can I learn Soukous guitar?

Tags: technique, guitar, african

I really like the sound of Soukous guitar playing, and would like to learn a bit of that. What would be good ways of doing this? I'm not great at picking at all, I'm a happy amateur chord strummer, so both newbie resources as well as advanced stuff for getting better later is appreciated. Online, books or DVD's are all OK.

Comment: You'll need to be able to pick. Whether you practice on western-style picking, or go straight in and learn to pick as you learn Soukous patterns, probably doesn't matter. Maybe practice some bluegrass rolls? (Google it)

Answer (score 1):

For every genre, the method is the same. You listen to a lot of the music, and you try to play along. You transcribe your favorite bits and figure out the structure, the chords and the scales. There are some genres where a lot of those bits are well-established. Blues, for example, is the 12-bar, the minor pentatonic, bending, etc. etc. and I don't know the music of the Congo well enough to give you that head start, but if you're going to learn a genre, that's how you do it.